# jenkins api authentication failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

I am using oauth authentication for jenkins. I can successfully make api calls if i use my_user_name:api_token when my user name is explicitly configure in global security. It fails when my user name does not exist but a group which contains the user name and has all permissions.

Any idea about this phenomenon ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins api-token is obtained for a specific user `http://<jenkins-server>/user/<username>/configure` and can be used for that same user only.